# NO Email is sending in php even in Spam nor Inbox

Tags: php, email

What I need:

- when i submit a form  mail is sended to recipent.

My Problem :

- when submit form , form is Submitted ok with Reponse code:200k but no email is delivered.

here my code that im using:-

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $to = $_POST['email'];
    $from = "abc@gmail.com";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = "<div style=\"background:red;height:100px;width:100px;display:block;\">dfsdf</div>";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
    $headers  .= "From: $from\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Message has been sent....!";  
 }else{
    echo "Add an email address"; 
 }?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="testemail.php" method="post">
  <input name="email" type="text" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error log:

```
  HP Notice:  Undefined variable: form in /var/www/index2.php on line 192
[Tue Jun 10 19:09:10.799088 2014] [:error] [pid 3588] [client 127.0.0.1:48078] PHP  Notice:    Undefined index: WRCF-Name in /var/www/asana/index2.php on line 246
[Tue Jun 10 19:09:10.799095 2014] [:error] [pid 3588] [client 127.0.0.1:48078] PHP Notice:    Undefined index: WRCF-Email in /var/www/asana/index2.php on line 251
[Tue Jun 10 19:09:37.272245 2014] [:error] [pid 3545] [client 127.0.0.1:48096] PHP Notice:   Undefined index: save-stuff in /var/www/asana/index2.php on line 123, referer: http://localhost/index2.php

sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
```

installing send mail:

```
    sudo apt-get install sendmail
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    sendmail is already the newest version.
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    libfluidsynth1 libmad0 libmikmod2 libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-mixer1.2
    libsdl1.2debian libwebp4 linux-headers-3.11.0-19
    linux-headers-3.11.0-19-generic linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic
    linux-image-extra-3.11.0-19-generic musescore-soundfont-gm sauerbraten-data
```

Comment: What do your mail server logs tell you?

Comment: check the logs and try phpMailer library

Comment: sending this from local maschine ? or from a server ?

Comment: Is Local Smtp or senmail installed on your environment from where you are testing?

Comment: You don't have a local mail server installed. Even if it's not sendmail, the other "big" ones (postfix, exim, etc..) create a sendmail symlink. since you don't have sendmail at all, you don't have ANY mail server installed.

Comment: First step should be to stop using mail function and use PhpMailer instead. It has error reporting and handles mail much better. Here is a tutorial: http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#1

Comment: i have install send mail server in my localhost .

Comment: what environment is this?  shared server? what version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Look like you haven't can a program installed that php can use to send email.

Install Sendmail

Comment: This maybe of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963688/how-to-send-email-from-php-without-smtp-server-installed

Basically you shouldn't really use php mail function, as it can be very insecure.  It's better to use an existing library that have their own ways of sending email.

Comment: Still upvote because installing sendmail would solve the issue for now.

Comment: i have installed send mail server on my localhost even then its not working

Comment: how did you install sendmail? and what flavour of Os are you using?